# How does Hyperledger Fabric ensure the integrity of state in couchdb?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In version 1.x of Fabric you can use Couchdb as a state store.  How does Fabric ensure the integrity of the state?  For example, what if someone manipulated the state outside of Fabric by directly accessing Couchdb on a specific node.  At a minimum that could cause that node to be inconsistent with the rest of the network.

Answer (score 1):

The way to detect someone has manipulated and tempered state in one of the peers is to leverage and carefully define endorsement policies.

For example suppose you have two organizations and each have two peers: OrgA, OrgB and peer1_orgA, peer2_orgA, peer1_orgB, peer2_orgB. Hence you can define an endorsement policy which will require endorsement of all 4 peers. Next, suppose `peer1_orgA` got compromised and state forged.

Since client has to satisfy the endorsement policy it will send transaction proposal to all peers, peers will simulate transaction and return RWSet based on the state and signature on hashed RWSet.

Now, since state of `peer1_orgA` forged it will return different RWSet and therefore signature will differ as a consequence client won't be able to satisfy the endorsement policy moreover it will be able to discover that result of `peer1_orgA` has diverged.

This allows you to prevent fork in the state, as well as takes care of non-determinism ensuring integrity of the state.

Comment: This is highly dependent on *how* state is calculated in the application, correct?  If someone tampers with an earlier version of the state (delete it) outside of the application (directly accessing couchdb)  it may not be reflected in the state calculation as the application may alway use the most recent version.  This is in contrast to say a merkle tree where altering anything in tree results in a new root.   So in reality, the only way to be sure that couchdb hasn't been locally altered is to run an audit over the whole db and see how it compares to others.

Comment: what is RWSet in the answer?

Comment: RWSet is a shortcut for read-write set, which captures all read and writes during chaincode simulation.

Comment: @ArtemBarger I tried to run this experiment on 2 Org (having 2 peer each) network with Couchdb as state database. The endorsement policy is set to -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')" . The initial data in all 4 peers was {Key: "1", Owner: "John"} .I opened the fauxton Couchdb interface for peer1.org1 and changed the owner to "Doe" and then ran an invoke method of chaincode to change the owner to "Smith". The invoke ran successfully and now the owner is "Smith" in all 4 peers. Per your above answer, I was hoping that invoke would fail as RWSet hash would differ during endorsement.